# Mac Anaconda Python 3.7 Update Permission Error

Tags: python, permissions, anaconda

When I try to install Python 3.7 on conda (conda install -c anaconda python=3.7 AND conda install python=3.7) i get the following error:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(544): An error occurred while installing package 'anaconda::anaconda-navigator-1.9.6-py37_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/anaconda33zz6ly4j'
```

Any help would be appreciated!